# Out of memory exception Error when generating a SSRS report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I'm creating an SSRS report using report builder that generated large amount of data based on from to dates parameters.

If I run the report up to 3 months the report works fine, however when generating the report for a longer period generating larger amount of data an system out of memory exception error is thrown.

Note that if I run the query for the same period but from inside the data set it will be generated in seconds.

Also when generating the report from 
http://servername/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx it will keep loading without generating any data, I've tried to modify the rsreportserver.config file with the following with no success

```
<MemorySafetyMargin>80</MemorySafetyMargin>
        <MemoryThreshold>90</MemoryThreshold>
        <WorkingSetMaximum>4000000</WorkingSetMaximum>
        <WorkingSetMinimum>2400000</WorkingSetMinimum>
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it has been a while like 11 month, but did you check The timeout in your dataset properties? [Timeoutsetting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMOwl.png)